# Filtrar un array dentro de otro array

Tags: javascript, angular

explico mi situación quiero filtrar la respuesta de mi API que devuelve un arreglo

tengo esta data de prueba

```
let prodPrueba = [
      {
        id: "B801278",
        variation: "B801278-18",
      },

      {
        id: "PC002",
        variation: "PC002",
      },
    ];
```

el id es el codigo de un producto seleccionado y la variation es valga la redundancia la variacion seleccionada de un producto algo por ejemplo como un zapato con codigo B801278 y su variacion de talla 18 es la propiedad variation B801278-18

esta es mi respuesta desde el backend

```
let dataResponse = [
  {
  codProduct: "PC002",
  created_at: "2021-01-19T11:28:06.000000Z",
  desc: null,
  html_description: null,
  html_short_description: null,
  id_kit: null,
  kit: [],
  manufacturer: null,
  material: null,
  name: "Kit de Limpeza",
  id: "PC002",
  status: "active",
  tags: null,
  theme: null,
  title: null,
  type: null,
  variations: 
  [
    {
      product: "PC002", 
      cod: "U", 
      sku: "U", 
      product_sku: "PC002", 
      price: 96000,
    }
  ]

  },
  {
    codProduct: "ENG792015_9",
    created_at: "2021-01-19T11:27:59.000000Z",
    desc: null,
    html_description: null,
    html_short_description: null,
    id_kit: null,
    kit: [],
    manufacturer: null,
    material: null,
    name: "Charm en Plata.",
    id: "ENG792015_9",
    status: "active",
    tags: null,
    theme: null,
    title: null,
    type: null,
    variations: [
      {
        cod: "U",
        product: "ENG792015_9",
        product_sku: "ENG792015_9",
        price: 415000,
        sku: "U"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    codProduct: "B801278",
    created_at: "2021-01-19T11:27:30.000000Z",
    desc: null,
    html_description: null,
    html_short_description: "Set de Regalo Brazalete en Plata Clip",
    id_kit: null,
    kit: [],
    manufacturer: null,
    material: null,
    name: "Set de Regalo Brazalete en Plata, Clip",
    id: "B801278",
    status: "active",
    tags: null,
    theme: null,
    title: null,
    type: null,
    variations: [
      {
        cod: "U",
        price: 950000,
        product: "B801278",
        product_sku: "B801278",
        sku: "U"
      },
      {
        cod: "20",
        price: 950000,
        product: "B801278",
        product_sku: "B801278-20",
        sku: "U",
      },
      {
        cod: "19",
        price: 950000,
        product: "B801278",
        product_sku: "B801278-19",
        sku: "U",
      },
      {
        cod: "18",
        price: 950000,
        product: "B801278",
        product_sku: "B801278-18",
        sku: "U",
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Como notaran en la objeto "prodPrueba" tengo un 2 id que coinciden con los productos que devuelve el api y tambien dentro de "prodPrueba" tengo una propidad llamada "variation" que coincide con el "product_sku" de la variation que viene por cada producto que responde el api. Mi objetivo es filtrar la respuesta para obtener todas las variaciones excepto las que ya tengo almacenadas en "prodPrueba" he intentado los metodos filter,map,forEach pero no encuentro la manera. alguna suegerencia??

Answer (score 1):

Propongo la siguiente solución haciendo el uso de:

1. [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) Filtra solo los elementos que se desea
2. [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) Prueba si al menos un elemento de la matriz
   pasa la prueba implementada por la función proporcionada
3. [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) Verifica si una matriz contiene un valor

Consiguiendo:

```js
let prodPrueba = [{
    id: "B801278",
    variations: "B801278-18",
}];


let dataResponse = [{
        codProduct: "PC002",
        created_at: "2021-01-19T11:28:06.000000Z",
        desc: null,
        html_description: null,
        html_short_description: null,
        id_kit: null,
        kit: [],
        manufacturer: null,
        material: null,
        name: "Kit de Limpeza",
        id: "PC002",
        status: "active",
        tags: null,
        theme: null,
        title: null,
        type: null,
        variations: [{
            product: "PC002",
            cod: "U",
            sku: "U",
            product_sku: "PC002",
            price: 96000,
        }]
    },


    {
        codProduct: "ENG792015_9",
        created_at: "2021-01-19T11:27:59.000000Z",
        desc: null,
        html_description: null,
        html_short_description: null,
        id_kit: null,
        kit: [],
        manufacturer: null,
        material: null,
        name: "Charm en Plata.",
        id: "ENG792015_9",
        status: "active",
        tags: null,
        theme: null,
        title: null,
        type: null,
        variations: [{
            cod: "U",
            product: "ENG792015_9",
            product_sku: "ENG792015_9",
            price: 415000,
            sku: "U"
        }]
    },


    {
        codProduct: "B801278",
        created_at: "2021-01-19T11:27:30.000000Z",
        desc: null,
        html_description: null,
        html_short_description: "Set de Regalo Brazalete en Plata Clip",
        id_kit: null,
        kit: [],
        manufacturer: null,
        material: null,
        name: "Set de Regalo Brazalete en Plata, Clip",
        id: "B801278",
        status: "active",
        tags: null,
        theme: null,
        title: null,
        type: null,
        variations: [{
                cod: "U",
                price: 950000,
                product: "B801278",
                product_sku: "B801278",
                sku: "U"
            },
            {
                cod: "20",
                price: 950000,
                product: "B801278",
                product_sku: "B801278-20",
                sku: "U",
            },
            {
                cod: "19",
                price: 950000,
                product: "B801278",
                product_sku: "B801278-19",
                sku: "U",
            },
            {
                cod: "18",
                price: 950000,
                product: "B801278",
                product_sku: "B801278-18",
                sku: "U",
            },

        ]
    }
]




let variations = dataResponse
    .filter(res => prodPrueba.some(id_prueba => id_prueba.id.includes(res.id)))[0]
    .variations.filter(v =>
        prodPrueba.some(v_prueba => !v_prueba.variations.includes(v.product_sku)))

console.log(variations);
```

Tomé como ejemplo el ultimo objeto de `dataResponse` haciendo uso del id. Se filtra prodPrueba desde dataResponse junto con some(), y verificando con include() que exista el id obteniendo el nuevo array con el objeto(id:'B801278'). Lugo se filtra en variations (`[0]`) de la misma forma, con la diferencia que se toma la propiedad variations de prodPrueba, y some() devolverá un nuevo array con los valores diferentes al indicado `!v_prueba.variations.includes(....)`

Espero ser de ayuda, saludos!